# Table-cell - width: 100% with table-layout: fixed;

Tags: html, css

This is the code without `table-layout: fixed` http://jsfiddle.net/CDUBv/11/
Needs be of `table-layout: fixed` because this is how it works `word-wrap: break-word`. Here, however, what happens if I add it: http://jsfiddle.net/CDUBv/12/ How to solve? `word-break: break-all` in the first page or add stable width in first div is not the solution.

Comment: Any special reason you are using table cells?

Comment: How to do it without tables?

Comment: I think you want your two images to be on the left and then the text to take up the remaining space on the right (allowing for long non-breaking strings and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different approach that might be close to what you need.

The HTML is:

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="t1">
        <img src="..."  width="50" width="50"/>
        <img src="..."  width="50" width="50"/>
    </div>
    <div id="t2">T2T2T2T2T2T2T2T2T2T ... T2T2T2T2T2T2T2T2T2T2T2T2T2</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```css
#table{
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
#t1{
    float: left;
}
#t1 img {
    vertical-align: top;
}

#t2{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I floated `#t1` to the left to get a shrink-to-fit width around the icons.

The content in `#t2` will then fill up the remainder of the width.

The trick to get the background colors is to add the black to the parent container and the red to the non-floated child element.

**Limitations**

If your content is very short, the `#t2` element will be shorter than `#t1` so you may want to add a min-height value to preserve the color pattern (black on left, red on right).

If you want to vertically center the icons, then you may need to specify a width for `#t1` and then absolutely position the icons.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/5j5Hz/